# Unsigned long long variable initialized with negative value

Tags: c++, variables, iostream, long-integer

The user inputs a value (through `<iostream>`) to unsigned long long variable. How can I detect, whether the input variable was negative? The input stream remains in a `good()`state. Can I do it without the use of additional `string` variable?

```
unsigned long long SafeInput(){
    unsigned long long buffer = 0;
        while (!(cin >> buffer) || cin.get() != '\n')
        {
            cout << "Error. Input again: ";
            cin.clear(); 
            cin.sync();
        }
    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: Can't you just static cast it to signed long long?

Comment: You can do it with an additional signed variable.

Comment: `signed long long` cuts the positive var. range twice comparing to `unsigned`. That's a bad solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the user to be able to use the full range of `unsigned long long`, then you have two options:

1. Use a string and parse it
2. Use a bigger (signed) integer type (maybe some special library needed for 128 bit integers)

Otherwise you can just treat the variable, as if it was a signed `long long` and test the most significant bit (or temporarily cast it and perform a "normal" comparison).

Answer (score 3):

You can't, at least not directly.  For various historical reasons, C++
allows the minus sign even when inputting unsigned values.  The best you
can do is to check before the field is read:

```
input >> std::ws;       //  Skips white space
if ( input.peek() == '-' ) {
    //  Input begins with minus sign...
}
//  Do input.
```

Once the value has been converted, the information concerning the text
which generated it has been lost.

Comment: I've added a code which just  checks whether the input is a number, Do you know, how can I add your fragment to my code in order to detect negative? For example, if it is negative, the programs should show a message "Error" and ask to input again.

Comment: @Jack The code above (executed before you enter the number) checks whether the user has entered a minus sign.

Comment: What do you mean by "input"? Should I replace it by "cin"? Anyway, it is either undentified or causes stack overflow exception

Comment: @Jack `input` is whatever istream you happen to be reading from.  (Except in toy programs, it won't be `std::cin`, but some `std::istream&` argument to the function.)

Answer (score 0):

Entering a negative number when `cin` expects an unsigned one will set the fail state for the stream, which you can query by `cin.fail()`.

However, inputting numbers greater than `ULLONG_MAX` will also set the fail state, so you can't know whether the value entered by the user was too small or too big by checking `cin.fail()`.

If you want to detect only negative input, then you need to use a string as a helper variable, as mentioned by [UniversE](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2534472/universe).

Comment: The `cin.fail()` flag won't be set, and that's the problem. I'm searching for a solution which can be performed without `string` var.